# How can I load/save minecraft worlds to a USB drive, on a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There are a number of answers about running all of Minecraft and MineOS from a USB drive.  Here I'm asking about only loading/saving worlds from the USB stick.  Running all of Minecraft from USB is too slow.  I can copy the worlds from USB to the computer, play, then copy the files back to USB, but this is error prone.

So: can I insert a USB stick into an OSX Computer running Minecraft, and play worlds directly from that device?

A tutorial that does not answer the question is:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Playing_and_saving_Minecraft_on_a_thumb_drive#Mac
Other tutorials describe using DropBox and symbolic links, but that is not applicable for use on a guest computer you don't own.

Comment: Using $HOME would mess up the guest system minecraft, so is not a great answer, @JeffreyLin

Comment: @JeffreyLin setlocale how?

Comment: Not `setlocale`, my bad. You'd need to create a subshell somehow and run the script through that. You might want to ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) between the two folders (saves and the saves folder on your USB drive).
Instructions on doing this with your Minecraft worlds are shown at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Migrating_saved_game_data_to_the_cloud. Instead of using dropbox as your destination folder however, you can use a folder on your USB drive. The quote below from the Minecraft Wiki (link above) shows you how to do this on Mac OS using the terminal.

> ln -s ~/Dropbox/Minecraft/saves ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/saves

Replace **~/Dropbox/Minecraft/saves** with the destination folder.

Answer (score -1):

you can actuely save a World in a diffrent place (cloud, USB, etc)
by going into your minecraft "Saves" map and Copy the folder which is the world you wanna save 
but to use it you need to set it back into the "Saves" map of your minecraft or else it wont work

Comment: This question was explicitly about not having to do that.

Answer (score -5):

on the finder(or you can check on the search bar) you go to library than go to application support than navigate to .minecraft folder and find the save folder saves and the world should be there and you can either copy it or move it to the usb.

Comment: the asker is wanting to know how to play just the world off a USB. *"I can copy the worlds from USB to the computer, play, then copy the files back to USB, but this is error prone."*

Comment: are you kidding he changed the question thats not fair you cant mark me down for that

Comment: no they haven't, the edit grace period where sometimes edits can be made but not noted on the page as having been edited is i think 5 minutes, you posted your answer at 22:05 while the question was posted on 20:54 (according to the times that are displayed when you hove over the time above the name), that's over an hour after the question was posted, you just didn't read the question body properly